# Docker [FastAPI] building multiple images and not loading on localhost

Tags: docker, fastapi

This was just working last Friday but now suddenly when I try to run a `docker build -t app .` it builds multiple images (one is a copy of my code and the other is a copy of [tiangolo's](https://hub.docker.com/r/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi) code) and none of them works as expected nor do they contain the Dockerfile inside of the imaged OS. I expect when I run the container on port 8080 that the site should load when I open `http://localhost:8080`.

Am I not understanding something about how the build process works? What might have changed from last week? I was building and deleting these images many times with no issues running them. I also have an NGINX image that's doing the same thing. Any ideas are much appreciated. Thanks!

Here's the code:

**File structure:**

```
mainApp
  app 
     main.py   
  Dockerfile
```

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.8

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY ./app /app
```

**main.py**

```
import socket
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Served From": str(socket.gethostname())}
```

Comment: The build command only builds the image. Have you tried running a container based on that image?

Comment: Yes, apologies if I didn't specify that. I'm using Docker Desktop for Windows so once I build the image, I see two images show up in my images tab on Docker Desktop. Then I try to run the container (just one or both) and they still don't work when loading on the localhost port.
----------------------------
Edit: Suddenly I re-did the process after updating Docker Desktop and it now loads the localhost pages... however it's still generating 2 images for some reason I don't understand.

Comment: Frustratingly... after restarting my IDE and updating Docker it works all of sudden as expected excluding the fact that 2 images are being created when I run the 'docker build -t name .' command... just wondering why that is happening now. It seems to mount that base image and then create a separate one with my config from the Dockerfile..
----------------edit: annnd.. it stopped loading again out of the blue.

Comment: If it helps I was attempting to run a test on this by pushing 1000 threads of requests to the server

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why my `docker build -t image .` is still building 2 images that are showing in the windows desktop app but I found that localhost was not working rather I had to use 'http://127.0.0.1:[port]/' to load the web pages. I don't know why yet as I was using localhost just the day before.